# How do I move values to empty cells in another dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. Both have a 'year' column and a series of other IDs like this:

```
year <- c("1990", "2000", "2010", "", "")
name <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5")
other <- c("dhg", "fsgh", "fgskgs", "fsjg", "wod")
df1 <- data.frame(name, year)
```

```
year <- c("", "", "", "2009", "2013")
name <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5")
df2 <- data.frame(name, year)
```

I want to merge them so that the column that is not common to both is kept but all the year values are merged into a single column. So the desired result is:

```
year <- c("1990", "2000", "2010", "2009", "2013")
name <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5")
other <- c("dhg", "fsgh", "fgskgs", "fsjg", "wod")
df3 <- data.frame(name, year)
```

Tried to use merge for this but I can't get it to work. I'm sure the solution is simple. Does anyone have any ideas how to get the desired output? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the code for `df1`, the column for `other`seems to be missing, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple base R solution using `ifelse`.

First convert `year`,which is a factor, to character in both dataframes:

```
df1$year <- as.character(df1$year)
df2$year <- as.character(df2$year)
```

Then use `ifelse` to insert the relevant years in (the more comprehensive) `df1`:

```
df1$year <- ifelse(df1$year=="", df2$year, df1$year)
df1
  name year  other
1  id1 1990    dhg
2  id2 2000   fsgh
3  id3 2010 fgskgs
4  id4 2009   fsjg
5  id5 2013    wod
```

Comment: Hey, this is a great solution but I have a small problem/ question. In the example I gave, all of the rows will be filled but in my actual dataset, there will still be some blanks left over. I think this code might be filling all blank rows rather than matching with the relevant name (id1, id2, etc.). Is that right? If so, how would I fix the problem?

Comment: Can you get me a snippet of your data that includes what you call 'some blanks'?

Comment: Hey I actually figured out a solution - you just rbind the two dataframes and then remove duplicates in the name column. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

By combining a merge and a paste function, you can merge the 'name' column and paste the 'year' columns to create a single column. Then you can simply add the 'other' vector to the dataframe by creating a new column.

```
year <- c("1990", "2000", "2010", "", "")
name <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5")
other <- c("dhg", "fsgh", "fgskgs", "fsjg", "wod")
df1 <- data.frame(name, year)

year <- c("", "", "", "2009", "2013")
name <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5")
df2 <- data.frame(name, year)

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)
df3$year <- paste(df1$year, df2$year)
df3$other <- other
```

Creating the following dataframe ('df3'):

```
 name  year  other
1  id1 1990     dhg
2  id2 2000    fsgh
3  id3 2010  fgskgs
4  id4  2009   fsjg
5  id5  2013    wod
```

Comment: If you use `sep = ""`inside the call to `paste`you can avoid the spaces before and, respectively after the `year` values

Answer (score 0):

We can replace empty values with `NA` in both the dataframe, do an inner join and use `coalesce` to combine two columns.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1 %>%  na_if(""), df2 %>% na_if(""), by = "name") %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate(year = coalesce(year.x, year.y)) %>%
  select(names(df1))

#  name year  other
#1  id1 1990    dhg
#2  id2 2000   fsgh
#3  id3 2010 fgskgs
#4  id4 2009   fsjg
#5  id5 2013    wod
```

**data**

Including `other` column in `df1`

```
year <- c("1990", "2000", "2010", "", "")
name <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5")
other <- c("dhg", "fsgh", "fgskgs", "fsjg", "wod")
df1 <- data.frame(name, year, other)


year <- c("", "", "", "2009", "2013")
name <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5")
df2 <- data.frame(name, year)
```